# Getting a field from a Collection in a column

Tags: wpf, grid, observablecollection

Im searching for a way to get a column from a collection inside a collection which is the source of my grid.

Like this:

```
<dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{tools:ValidationBinding Model.Costs}">
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Costs.Description" Header="Description" />
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Costs.CurrencyAbbrevation" />
</dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

My source of my grid is Model.Costs and this collection has another collection Costs. I need the Description field from that collection. Any idea's?

Overview:

This is the source of the grid:

```
 public virtual ObservableCollection<ShipmentLineCost> Costs { get; set; }
```

This also contains an observablecollection:

```
public virtual ObservableCollection<SettlementCost> Costs { get; set; }
```

And I want the Description value from it in my grid:

```
public string Description { get { return (Product == null) ? "" : Product.Description + ";" + SettlementUnit.Description + ";" + CurrencyAbbreviation; } } –
```

Greets

Comment: Are you using MVVM here? If so, the ItemSource is bound to a Viewmodel, it should be straight forward to access the required data through the ViewModel...

Comment: Yes I'm using MVVM, can't reach the description field from the collection costs inside the collection costs. No errors, but also no output.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer when you haven't even shown us what any of your data structures look like?

Answer (score 0):

To get the `DataContext` you require you will have to work back up the visual tree and also use a `DataTemplate` as follows

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Doing this directly on the `Header` property will not work because it cannot be resolved in-place as the column is an abstract object not appearing in the tree.

Comment: Ur building a headertemplate, using a property Description. But thats not really what I need. I need to get my description from the collection Costs inside the grid, which has the source Costs collection from another class.